# Get specific percentage of characters that are changed

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics

In the code below I am trying to get a DNA sequence and change every 150th character to a random letter to one of the following: "A","T","C","G". The only trouble I am having is getting the loop to stop when 1% of the total sequence length is substituted.

```
import random

i  = 0 
percent_changed = 0 

while i <= len(DNASeq) and percent_changed <= 1.0:
    char = DNASeq[i].replace( DNASeq[i], random.choice(["A","T","C","G"]))
    i += 150
    percent_changed = i / len(DNASeq)
    print(char)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the second conditional to `percent_changed <= 0.01` given that you are not multiplying `percent_changed` by 100 in your while loop.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!